# Правильная обработка null в большой вложенности данных

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! К примеру, необходимо загрузить JSON с сервера и отобразить некоторые поля в UI. Но порой, вложенность данных очень большая и один объект может содержать кучу других вложенных объектов, которые в свою очередь - тоже содержат такие же вложенные объекты. И есть вероятность, что порой из-за багов на сервере могут некоторые поля содержать null.

Если писать логику получения и отображения данных для Java модели на основе JSON, то из-за большой вложенности данных код начинает засоряться проверками на null, а так же если необходимо повесить дополнительную логику на обработку данных, то все становится еще плачевнее в плане читаемости.

Я создал небольшой пример (Выдуманный) и постарался разделить на отдельные методы логику по получению данных из модели и их отображению. Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я поступаю?? Или же необходимо выкидывать исключения, если данные пришли, например, невалидные или же необходимый объект == null.

Предполагается что в реальных задачах модель Job может содержать гораздо больше данных.

Заранее спасибо, за вашу помощь.

```
public class Main {
static class Job {
    private int id;
    private List<Shipment> shipments;
    private Driver driver;
    private Truck truck;

    /* Предположим, что тут конструктор, а так же геттеры и сеттеры */
}

static class Shipment {
    private int id;
    private String goods;
    private Address address;

    /* Предположим что тут конструктор, а так же геттеры и сеттеры */
}

static class Address {
    private int id;
    private String city;

    /* Предположим что тут конструктор, а так же геттеры и сеттеры */
}

static class Driver {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    /* Предположим что тут конструктор, а так же геттеры и сеттеры */
}

static class Truck {
    private int id;
    private String number;

    /* Предположим что тут конструктор, а так же геттеры и сеттеры */
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Job job = load();
    updateUI(job);
}

/**
 * Эмулирует заргузку модели Job
 * @return Job
 */
static Job load() {
    Driver driver = new Driver(1, "John", "Kristoff");
    Truck truck = new Truck(1, "NV157");
    Address address = new Address(1, "New York");
    Shipment shipment = new Shipment(1, "Coffee", address);

    List<Shipment> shipments = Collections.singletonList(shipment);
    return new Job(1, shipments, driver, truck);
}

static void updateUI(Job job) {
    if (job == null) {
        return;
    }

    showShipments(job.getShipments());
    showDriver(job.getDriver());
    showTruck(job.getTruck());
}

static void showShipments(List<Shipment> shipments) {
    if (shipments == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (Shipment shipment: shipments) {
        System.out.println("Goods in the shipment: " + shipment.getGoods());

        if (shipment.getAddress() != null) {
            System.out.println("Shipment`s address: " + shipment.getAddress().getCity());
        }
    }
}

static void showDriver(Driver driver) {
    if (driver == null) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Driver`s first name: " + driver.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Driver`s last name: " + driver.getLastName());
}

static void showTruck(Truck truck) {
    if (truck == null) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Truck: " + truck.getNumber());
}
```

}

Comment: Напишите простой класс валидатор, который проверяет данные на входе, чтобы в дальнейшем не размазывать проверки на null по всему коду. Можно использовать [JSR-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/). В современных языках есть [элвис оператор](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls), а у Oracle только такой [буллшит](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html), к сожалению.

Comment: Возможно проблема не в корректности данных, а в загрузке с сервера целого дерева объектов. Попробуйте разбить этот объект на минимальные логические единицы. И используйте их по месту. В противном случае используйте  Optional.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как лучше избежать NullPointerException при большой вложенности?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600917/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-nullpointerexception-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8)

Comment: Проблема высосанная из пальца. Я тоже так люблю делать, чтобы не работать:)

Answer (score -1):

Загрузка такого дерева объектов в UI достаточно опрометчиво. Лишние связи нужно разрывать. Объекту Job достаточно иметь объекты "ссылка" на Driver,Track:

```
public class Job {
    private int id;
    private ReferenceData driver;
    private ReferenceData truck;
}

public class ReferenceData {
    private int id;
    private String description;
}
```

Объект ссылка помогает разбивать сложные объекты на отдельные единицы. Особенно когда они обрабатываются отдельно.

При обработке полного дерева объектов связь лучше обернуть в Optional. Подход позволяет избегать NullPointerException при обработке:

```
static void showDriver(Optional<Driver> driver) {
    driver.foreach(d -> {
        System.out.println("Driver`s first name: " + d.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Driver`s last name: " + d.getLastName());
    }
}
```