# Как лучше избежать NullPointerException при большой вложенности в Java?

Tags: java, исключения

Под большой вложенностью имеется ввиду код вида:

```
param = foo.getSomthing1().getSomthig2().getSomthing3() ...
```

При этом в каждом вызове может вылететь `NullPointerException`.
Хорошим примером является сгенерированные классы по XSD схеме.
Мне нужно вытащить и присвоить некоторое значение, и если на пути встретится хоть одна отсутствующая нода (`null` в Java) - мне нужно присвоить `null`.

Один из вариантов, это `if` вида:

```
if (foo != null && foo.getSomthing1() != null && ....) {
    param = foo.getSomthing1().getSomthig2().getSomthing3() ...
}
```

При этом код становится нечитабельным. И простой конвертер объекта, сгенеренного по XSD схеме класса в плоскую Java структуру выглядит ужасно.

Есть вариант поместить в `try catch` :) Но это будет выглядеть ещё хуже, не говоря уже о производительности.

Слышал про операторы `?.`, `?:`, `?[]`, но заставить их работать локально у меня не получилось, а так было бы интересным решением:

```
param = foo?.getSomthing1()?.getSomthig2()?.getSomthing3() ...
```

**UPD:** вариант с `?.` был взят из неавторитетного источника. Имелся ввиду вероятно C#.

Подскажите, какие ещё могут быть способы?

Comment: Не тянет на полноценный ответ, зато полностью решает проблему - переходите на Scala.

Comment: `?.` - это C#. Переходи на шарп и используй :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, да я уже понял, натыкался в контексте Java, говорили мол с 1.8 работает. Источник был не авторитетный:)

Comment: ?. - это  groovy. http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator Код на java является так же кодом на groovy. Плюс в groovy есть удобные классы для работы с xml и html.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Есть такой вариант, но только для Java 8:

```
private Optional<String> get(First first) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(first.getSecond())
            .map(Second::getThird)
            .map(Third::getFourth)
            .map(Fourth::getString);
}
```

Допустим у нас есть класс **First**, который в свою очередь содержит в себе поле с классом **Second**, который содержит **Third**, который содержит **Fourth** в котором нужное нам поле, пусть это будет **String**.

Итого, чтобы получить string из **Fourth**, имея экземпляр класса **First**, нам нужна следующая конструкция `String someString = first.getSecond().getThird().getFourth().getString()`.

Имея вышеописанный метод, мы делаем следующее:
`String someString = get(first).orElse(null);`

Если один из вложенных классов окажется **null**, то мы просто получим `someString = null`, либо вместо **null** можно указать default значение.

**Remark**

Речь идет об использовании специального класса [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) введенного в Java 8. Для Java 7 можно воспользоваться [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) - там тоже есть аналогичный класс `Optional`

Comment: Например вам нужно вытащить некий **String** он находится в   `first.getSecond().getThird().getFourth().getString`  то это будет   выглядеть как `String test = get(first).orElse(null);`

Comment: Подробнее расписал в ответе, выложил пример https://bitbucket.org/snippets/n0c1ip/77x6G

Comment: Пример лучше бы в сам ответ добавить. )

Comment: Для 8 Java замечательно, ну а если 7 ая java или ниже?

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa написать свою монаду

Answer (score 13):

Можно использовать [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) и `ifPresent`:

К примеру, если есть такой класс:

```
public class TestClass{

    public Optional<TestClass> getSomthing1(){
        return Optional.of(this);
    }

    public Optional<TestClass> getSomthing2(){
        return Optional.of(this);
    }
}
```

То использовать можно будет так:

```
TestClass test = new TestClass();
test.getSomthing1().ifPresent(t -> t.getSomthing2());
```

То есть, мы возвращаемое значение заворачиваем в `Optional`.

P.S. это с Java 8 только доступно

Comment: Интересно, спасибо. С xsd это не проканает, а вообще любопытно.

Answer (score 7):

Есть шаблон проектирования, который называется [Null object](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_(%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Данный шаблон проектирования рекомендуется использовать, когда:

- Объект требует взаимодействия с другими объектами. Null Object не устанавливает нового взаимодействия — он использует уже установленное взаимодействие.
- Какие-то из взаимодействующих объектов должны бездействовать
- Требуется абстрагирование «общения» с объектами, имеющими NULL-значение.

Также на эту тему можно посмотреть видео с примерами от [Егора Бугаенко](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3aNJX7AP3M) (eng).

Основной недостатком такого подхода - количество созданных Null object классов.

Comment: Ну вот только он не нужен при простой проверке на null. Как его использовать для выше поставленной цели?

Answer (score 4):

Если решитесь использовать try/catch, можно создать вспомогательный static метод:

```
public class Util {
  public static <T> T nullIfNPE(Supplier<T> f) {
      try {
          return f.get();
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
          return null;
      }
  }
}
```

Используете так:

```
String param = Util.nullIfNPE(() -> foo.getSomthing1().getSomthig2());
```

А если импортировать статически этот метод, то даже так:

```
String param = nullIfNPE(() -> foo.getSomthing1().getSomthig2());
```

Вполне лаконично =)

Comment: Стоит отметить, что само наличие try/catch блока почти не влияет на производительность, а вот обработка возникающих исключений - влияет. Т.е. если в лямбде (Supplier'е) NPE будет редко выбрасываться - с производительностью все будет ок.

Comment: Использование исключений для обыкновенного control flow наверное всё же не самая лучшая идея.

Comment: ура созданию и выбросу стэка на каждый чих

Comment: @Etki, в вопросе описана конкретная ситуация с автосгенеренными классами, которые мы трогать не можем. Данный ответ полностью решает проблему нечитабельности, хоть и страдает в производительности. Ваш сарказм неуместен, по мне, так это лучший ответ применительно к описанной в вопросе проблеме.Лучший по голосам ответ описанную проблему не решает.

Comment: @pegoopik Хорошо, ждем вопроса про производительность

Answer (score 2):

Тернарный оператор работает следующим образом.

```
ComplexityObjectRef cObj;

String res = cObj.getFirst() == null ? "message for this cond" : 
cObj.getFirst().getSecond() == null ? "message for this cond" : 
cObj.getFirst().getSecond().getThird() == null ? "message for this cond" : 
cObj.getFirst().getSecond().getThird().getResult();
```

Кода много для такой проверки, но он вполне читабельный и понятный, и использование тернарного опретора для **java 7** и ниже вполне приемлимый вариант.

Comment: Громоздко. Вариант с простым if, описанный в вопросе выглядит  читабельнее и занимает меньше места.

Answer (score 1):

Написал небольшую обертку, которая решает проблему `NullPointerException`

```
public static class NPEChecker<T> {
    public final T value;

    public NPEChecker(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <R> NPEChecker<R> invoke(Function<T, R> function) {
        if (value == null)
            return new NPEChecker<>(null);

        R result = function.apply(value);
        return new NPEChecker<>(result);
    }
}
```

С ее помощью, конструкция вида:

```
AnnotatedType[] result = Solution.class
                .getAnnotatedInterfaces()
                .getClass()
                .getAnnotatedInterfaces();
```

Преобразуется в следующее:

```
AnnotatedType[] result = new NPEChecker<>(Solution.class)
            .invoke(Class::getAnnotatedInterfaces)
            .invoke(AnnotatedType[]::getClass)
            .invoke(Class::getAnnotatedInterfaces)
            .value;
```

Comment: А чем это принципиально отличается от [ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/601039/183980) с `Optional`?

Comment: @Roman, тем, что не требует вмешательства в класс Solution.

Comment: @pegoopik Так и с `Optional` не требуется: `AnnotatedType[] result = Optional.of(Solution.class) .map(Class::getAnnotatedInterfaces) .map(AnnotatedType[]::getClass) .map(Class::getAnnotatedInterfaces) .orElse(null);`

Comment: @Roman принципиально ничем, просто решил запились свою реализацию.

Comment: @Roman, не тот ответ с Optional посмотрел.Но и от принятого ответа отличается тем, что решение универсально. Не нужно на каждый чих создавать отдельную функцию, типа private Optional<String> get(First first).

Answer (score -2):

Я, конечно, могу ошибаться, или не понять сути вопроса, но нашёл решение попроще предложенных:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String param;
        try {
            param= String.valueOf(foo.q().w().e().r().t());
        } catch (Exception ignored) { 
            param= "null"; 
        }
        System.out.println(param);
    }

    private MainClass q() {
        return new MainClass();
    }

    private MainClass w() {
        return new MainClass();
    }

    private MainClass e() {
        return new MainClass();
    }

    private MainClass r() {
        return null;
    }

    private MainClass t() {
        return new MainClass();
    }

}
```

Масса кода, чтоб было готовая проверка при необходимости, но, по сути, решение таково:

```
String param;
try {
    param = String.valueOf(foo.q().w().e().r().t());
} catch (Exception ignored) {
    param = "null";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Пожалуй, самый простой и понятный способ:

```
try {
    param = foo.getSomething1().getSomething2()...;
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    param = null;
}
```

Надеюсь, что это решило вашу проблему.