# try/catch вместо if null

Tags: java, if, try-catch

Часто бувает несколько и больше аргументов в условии которые необходимо проверить на null. Мне надоело перечислять if(a!=null && b!=null || c!=null) и т.д. Я стал просто обрамлять в try/catch и если что-то не так то просто вывожу сообщение, что одно из условий отсутствует. Понятно что в некоторых случаях необходимо знать, что я получаю и приходится использовать if.

Но все же является такая практика с t/c нормальной?

Comment: Нет, использование исключений - дорогая конструкция.

Comment: Исключения созданы для того, что бы отлавливать исключительные ситуации. Написание всевозможных проверок, это тоже часть работы программиста. В таком виде другой человек может со спокойной душой подумать о допустимости null значения и потом долго думать, что не так.

Comment: лучше всего делать так, что бы null был не возможен в принципе. 

I call it my billion-dollar mistake. It was the invention of the null reference in 1965.(c) Tony Hoare

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600922/16095

Comment: Если уверены, что нет других причин NPE, то можно и так. Хотя правильнее проверить всё индивидуально. `if (a == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("a == null");` `if (b == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("b == null");` И сразу видно с чем проблема. И даже более глубокий смысл появляется вместо абстрактного NPE. Неправильный аргумент, а что ты хотел?

Answer (score 5):

Примените что-то подобное:

```
private boolean isNull(Object... objects) {
    if (objects != null) {
        for (Object object : objects) {
           if(object==null)
              return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


//использование
if(isNull(a, b, c))
   //blah-blah
```

Comment: Если множественное число, то корректней назвать `areNulls`.

Comment: Ну, это немного противоречит *Java naming convention*, но в целом я не против

Comment: Хм, скорее `isAnyNull`?

Comment: @VladD - точно! И Naming Convention цел и смысл остался

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос не в длине кода. Проверка на `null` является правильным, хорошим стилем.

Дело в том, что игнорируя проверку на `null`, вы тем самым подавляете не только эти, ожидаемые вами ошибки, но и все другие потенциальные баги в вашей программе. Проверка параметров вручную позволит приложению упасть в случае, если где-то в другом месте у вас ошибка. Если же вы будете ловить все ошибки скопом, то у вас ошибка в другом месте программы, приводящая к такому же исключению, будет поймана и выдаст ложное сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 4):

Конструкция try/catch обходится дороже. Приведу тест замера времени для 1000000000 вызовов методов проверяющих аргумент на `null` явно и в попытке и выведу результат замера в консоль:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start, end;

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            method(null);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Check null: " + (end-start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            methodWithTry(null);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Try/catch: " + (end-start));
    }

    public static int method(String s) {
        if (s != null) {
            return s.length();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static int methodWithTry(String s) {
        try {
            return s.length();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Check null: 15
Try/catch: 1404
```

**UPD:**

Комментарий *Artem Konovalov* подтвердился. Судя по всему мой код был автоматически оптимизирован из-за того, что не был использован результат методов. Скорректированный код дает иные результаты:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = 0;
        long start, end;

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            if (i%2==0) {
                c += method(null);
            } else {
                c += method(i);
            }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Check null: " + (end-start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            if (i%2==0) {
                c += methodWithTry(null);
            } else {
                c += methodWithTry(i);
            }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Try/catch: " + (end-start));        
    }

    public static int method(Integer i) {
        if (i != null) {
            return i.intValue();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static int methodWithTry(Integer i) {
        try {
            return i.intValue();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Результат:

```
Check null: 1702
Try/catch: 3654
```

Comment: try/catch почти в 100 раз дороже, но его абсолютная стоимость похоже все равно пренебрежимо мала - 0,000001404 мсек ?

Comment: @Kromster зачем платить больше? (c) Реклама.

Comment: У меня в тесте получилась не такая большая разница, в производительности. Порядка 2x. https://gist.github.com/izebit/e97b630e7d392f1b3dd8c65bdf40d1df

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov вы правы. Мой тест был некорректен из-за того, что не использовал результат функции и параметр функции был одинаковый. Дополнил ответ исправленным кодом.

Answer (score 2):

Однозначно, сказать нельзя, какой вариант лучше. В этой ситуации стоит учитывать несколько моментов.

Исключения, как правило, используются для *необычных* ситуаций, когда выполнение программы пошло не так, как задумывал программист - получены некорректные параметры, внешние ошибки и пр.

Из этого можно вывести, что:

1. Если вы пишите код, который будет доступен для вызова сторонними разработчиками, то выкидывание `NullPointerException` вполне оправдано.
2. Если этот код, является частью внутреннего компонента, то использование блока `try-catch-finally`, не вполне оправдано. Получение  `null`, говорит о том, что код некорректен, т.е. такая ситуация ненормальна. В идеале, в процессе отладки `null`  проверяется `assert'ами` и все подобные ситуации *вылавливаются* в программе.

Еще один довод против исключений, это более худная производительность. В моем [тесте](https://gist.github.com/izebit/e97b630e7d392f1b3dd8c65bdf40d1df), разница была **порядка 2x**.